# Where is 'physical disconnect of USB drive' sound located in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, system-sounds

All the answers I get from search engines give me the sound for 'ejecting' a USB drive and not the sound played when I actually pull the drive, which I am trying to change. I haven't found this notification in the 'sounds' menu.

Comment: That is in Control Panel, Sounds, Device Disconnect.  When I test, that is the sound I hear if a disconnect a drive. My recollection is that if the device is safe to disconnect there may not be a sound.

Comment: I hear one sound when I tell windows to 'eject' a drive, and a second when I pull the drive out of the USB slot. I find the sound for 'eject' in the sound menu, but not the sound for 'pull'.

Comment: No such thing. What you have is all there is except for what is in device disconnect.